# Continuity on finite interval

Tags: continuity, self-learning

Problem: $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Prove that there is an $\alpha>0$ such that $f(x)>\alpha$ for all $x$.

Please help in the steps of this proof!

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you're having trouble with? For example, what are some results you know about continuous functions? Do you know that $[a, b]$ is compact, and what implications this might have?

Comment: Perhaps, the intermediate value theorem could be useful here, but I am not sure if that is the case, since there is only one bound.

Comment: Check out the extreme value theorem.  Either use it if you are allowed to, or look at how it is proven.

Comment: Hmm, I can use this theorem, but I'm not sure how to do so without any specific values.

Comment: Consider the minimum of the function.

Comment: Well, if we must have some f(d)=0 because 0 is the minimum, I'm not sure how this helps.

Comment: It is given $f(x)>0,\, \forall x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: repeating the T.Bongers question: Do you know about compact sets?

Comment: No. It may have been mentioned, but I am not familiar with this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not, $\exists~(x_n)\subset[a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)\le\dfrac{1}{n}~\forall~n\in\mathbb Z^+.$

$(x_n)$ being bounded it has a convergent subsequence $(x_{r_n})\subset[a,b].$

Suppose $x_{r_n}\to c$ in $[a,b].$ Due to the continuity of $f$ at $c,~f(x_{r_n})\to f(c).$

But $0<f(x_{r_n})\le\dfrac{1}{r_n}\le\dfrac{1}{n}\to0\implies f(x_{r_n})\to0\implies f(c)=0!$